# Register accounts in the program

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, user-accounts

I want to make accounts for the users so when they enter his personal code the program reply with his name and info and continue with the app, i have this so far but i dont know how to code this.

```
print("Welcome to xxApp")

YourCode = input("Create your Code: ")
    if Yourcode in Users.txt
        #Continue with the program
    else
        Name = input("Please enter your name: ")
        Age = input("Enter your age: ")
        print(",Name,,YourCode,,Age,"your info has been saved")
        #and continue with the program
```

Comment: Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59121573/python-login-and-register-system-using-text-files), its pretty close to what you're doing and should give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if using a text file is the best idea for this - CSV might be better. However, this works for using a text file.

main.py:

```
def accounts():
    yourCode = input("Please enter your user code. \nIf you already have an account, type your account user code. \nOtherwise, enter a new one to create an account: ") # User types their code

    # Opens file of users in read mode
    with open("users.txt", "r") as rf:
        users = rf.readlines() # Creates a list of users in the .txt file to check
        # Checks each user in the file to see if they are already in the accounts list. Each user is split into their user_code, name and age
        for each_user in [user.split(",") for user in users]: 
            if each_user[0] == yourCode: # If the user is in the accounts list
                print(f"Welcome {each_user[1]}") # f{} string allows the name to be inserted easily into the print statement
                xxApp() # Program runs
                return None # Exit Statement to get out of the accounts function when the main program has finished
    # If the user reaches this stage, it means they are not in the account list
    with open("users.txt", "a") as af: # Open file in append
        name = input("Please enter your name: ")
        age = input("Enter your age: ")
        af.write(f"{yourCode},{name},{age}\n") # Adds the users info to the users.txt file
        print(f"Thank you {name}, your information has been added.")
        xxApp()


def xxApp():
    ... # Put your main program here


accounts()
```

users.txt after program run as here:
[image: ProgramRun]

```
NewUser1,Example,27
```

Comment: wow thanks, how i can do it without a text file?

Comment: Have a look into using CSV (comma-separated value) files in python. There is an inbuilt CSV library that you will have to import but then you should be able to use the csv.reader() function to read from the file. My answer above is effectively using the format that CSV files take but using the CSV library will allow you to maintain a better structure.