# Login System - Python - Follow Up

Tags: python-3.9

This is a continuation of my Login system/ actual code for my Hotel Booking system. I am not that great at programming so do pardon any mistakes that I did. I did sort out my previous issue but then another issue occurred after that. Here is the link to my previous issue: [Login System - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72022453/login-system-python).

```
print("WELCOME TO THE MAJESTIC HOTEL lOGIN SYSTEM")
print("************************************************")
account = input("Do you have an account? Yes or No: ")

def MainMenu():
    print("WELCOME TO THE MAJESTIC HOTEL\n")
    print(" 1 Room Booking\n")
    print(" 2 Rooms Info\n")
    print(" 3 Payment\n")
    print(" 4 Record\n")
    print(" 0 Exit\n")

    choice = int(input("="))

    if choice == 1:
        print(" ")
        Room_Booking()

    if choice == 2:
        print(" ")
        Room_Info()

    if choice == 3:
        print(" ")
        Payment()

    if choice == 4:
        print(" ")
        Record()

    if choice == 0:
        print(" ")
        Exit()

def Room_Booking():

    check_In = str(input(" Enter Check In Date: "))
    check_Out = str(input(" Enter Check Out Date: "))

    print(" \n")

    print(" 1 One Bed AC\n")
    print(" 2 One Bed Non-AC\n")
    print(" 3 Standard Bed AC\n")
    print(" 4 Standard Bed Non-AC\n")
    print(" 5 Three Bed AC\n")
    print(" 6 Three Bed Non-AC\n")
    print(" 7 Four Bed AC\n")
    print(" 8 Four Bed Non-AC\n")

    Room_Type = int(input(" Choose a room type from above: "))

    if Room_Type == 1:
        for line in open("rooms.txt", "r").readlines():
            x = line.split("-")
            if x[1] == 'One Bed AC':
                print(x)

def get_existing_users():
    with open("login.txt", "r" ) as f:
         for line in f.readlines():
    # This expects each line of a file to be (name, pass) separated by whitespace. 
             username, password = line.rstrip("\n").split(',')
             yield username, password

def authorised_details(username, password):
    return any((user == (username, password) for user in get_existing_users()))

def existing_Users(username):
    return any((usr_name == username) for usr_name, _ in get_existing_users())
# above is equivalent of:
#
# for usr_name, _ in get_existing_users():
#     if usr_name == username:
#        return True
# return False

def login():
count = 0
while count < 3:
    username = input("Enter Username: ")
    password = input("Enter a Password: ")
    if authorised_details(username, password):
        print("Welcome to the Majestic Hotel Booking System")
        MainMenu()
    if existing_Users(username):
        print("The password entered is wrong, please try again")
    print("The username entered is wrong, please try again")
    count = count + 1

def register():
    forename = input("Enter forename: ")
    surname = input("Enter Surname: ")
    year = input("Enter year you are born: ")
    if year <= '2004':
        print("You are old enough to register yourself")
        username = forename[0]+surname[0:3]+year[3:4]
        print("Username: ", username)
    
        password = input("Enter a password: ")
        file = open("login.txt","a")
        file.write(username + "," + password + "\n")
        file.close()
        MainMenu()
    else:
        print("Sorry you are not old enough to register by yourself")

if account == "No":
  print(register())

if account == "Yes":
  print(login())
```

I am using the details that I created for my previous problem and this was saved in a text file called "login.txt", it was saved like this:

```
RMoo0,door
```

I ran the code again and the issue occurred right at the end :

```
WELCOME TO THE MAJESTIC HOTEL LOGIN SYSTEM
************************************************
Do you have an account? Yes or No: Yes

Enter Username: RMoo0
Enter a Password: door
Welcome to the Majestic Hotel Booking System
WELCOME TO THE MAJESTIC HOTEL

 1 Room Booking

 2 Rooms Info

 3 Payment

 4 Record

 0 Exit

=1

 Enter Check In Date: 22
 Enter Check Out Date: 22
 

 1 One Bed AC

 2 One Bed Non-AC

 3 Standard Bed AC

 4 Standard Bed Non-AC

 5 Three Bed AC

 6 Three Bed Non-AC

 7 Four Bed AC

 8 Four Bed Non-AC

 Choose a room type from above: 1
['01', 'One Bed AC', '£30', 'Y\n']
['09', 'One Bed AC', '£30', 'Y\n']
The password entered is wrong, please try again
The username entered is wrong, please try again
Enter Username:
```

Can someone please help me out and explain the solution in a way that I will understand.

Comment: It's not clear to me what "the issue" is.  Right after calling `MainMenu()` you then check `if existing_Users(username)` (which presumably is `true`) and then print a message.  Then you print another message.  Then the loop repeats.  That's exactly what we're seeing.

Comment: Yes but the issue is that when I output this code, it prints "the password entered is wrong, please try again". I want to get rid of the last three lines that were outputted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is exactly what your loop is doing:

```
while count < 3:
    username = input("Enter Username: ")
    password = input("Enter a Password: ")
    if authorised_details(username, password):
        print("Welcome to the Majestic Hotel Booking System")
        MainMenu()
    if existing_Users(username):
        print("The password entered is wrong, please try again")
    print("The username entered is wrong, please try again")
    count = count + 1
```

So, after `MainMenu()` finishes, you do this:

- Check `if existing_Users(username)`, and if true print a message.
- Print another message, always.
- Increment a counter and re-start the loop, the first action of which is to prompt the user for input.

In a comment above, you state:

> I want to get rid of the last three lines that were outputted.

So... You don't want to print those last two lines, and you don't want to re-start the loop?  In that case, simply remove those `print` operations and make a loop just a non-looping block of code:

```
username = input("Enter Username: ")
password = input("Enter a Password: ")
if authorised_details(username, password):
    print("Welcome to the Majestic Hotel Booking System")
    MainMenu()
```

That way when `MainMenu()` completes, the program will simply terminate.

If you also want to add a `print` operation for when `authorised_details(username, password)` is `false`, you can add an `else` to cover that:

```
username = input("Enter Username: ")
password = input("Enter a Password: ")
if authorised_details(username, password):
    print("Welcome to the Majestic Hotel Booking System")
    MainMenu()
else:
    print("Login failed, please try again")
```

---

**Edit:** If you *do* want to loop but *only for authentication* then you can put this logic back into a loop and perhaps use a `break` after `MainMenu()`.  Something like this:

```
while count < 3:
    username = input("Enter Username: ")
    password = input("Enter a Password: ")
    if authorised_details(username, password):
        print("Welcome to the Majestic Hotel Booking System")
        MainMenu()
        break
    else:
        print("Login failed, please try again")
    count = count + 1
```

This will allow the loop to repeat, but not if the `if` condition was `true`.  In that case after running `MainMenu()` the `break` statement will exit the loop.

Comment: I want the user to have 3 chances, if they make a mistake when entering their details. Is there a way to implement this.

Comment: @Luvita132: In that case you'd have a loop again.  Just be aware that when the loop repeats, it will repeat.  So you'll get another prompt for the username (which you'd indicated you want to remove).  If what you mean is that you want the loop to not repeat after a successful execution of `MainMenu()` then you can use the `break` statement for that.  I've updated the answer with an example.